# How can JavaScript get data from a user's computer?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, security

How can Javascript (running from a website on a remote server) access data from a user's local computer?
I have access to all the user's computers and they are all using Chrome.
The data may be stored in a file, a database, I can even run a webserver on their computers if needed, etc.
Is there any way for my users to for example allow my website to access data from JavaScript?
(maybe be there is a Chrome setting but I still want their browser to be secure)

Comment: You can distribute a Chrome plugin, or use a Java applet.

Comment: Why do you want a browser for that? Since you say you can run a server on their computer, I think that might be a better choice since it has a lot more permissions. If it's because you want JavaScript, try Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are flexible as to where the data is stored in the user's computer.  In that case use [localStorage](http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/) or [Web SQL Databases](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/).  Web SQL Databases are no longer part of the HTML5 spec, but they are supported by Chrome.  Using either of these methods will store the data on the users computer - right in the browser in fact.

**Edit:**  In the application that provides the caller id data, have it launch your website with chrome passing in a querystring argument containing the needed caller id data.  Then in your page, have it listen to the `onstorage` event, and update the dropdown when the appropriate localStorage data has changed.

In your caller id app, call:

```
%ChromeInstallPath%\chrome.exe "http://foo.com/caller?Bill+Gates@425-882-8080"
```

In your `caller` handler, use this JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    localStorage.callerId = location.search;
};
```

In your page with the drop down list, use this JavaScript:

```
window.onstorage = function() {
    setDropDownFromCallerId(localStorage.callerId);
};
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specified that the data wasn't created by the remote website, but by another application.

Comment: @Matthew - Can you clarify then what the data storage requirements are?  You said "The data may be stored in a file, a database, I can even run a webserver on their computers if needed, etc.".  You can run a webserver on the client computer, but you can't populate `localStorage`?

Comment: I need to read more about localStorage, but I thought it was a space client-side that only the web app could access. Another software could write into this space and it would be accessible by JS on my website? I'll read more about it!! Thank you!

Comment: @Matthew - Have your caller id app open up chrome and load a page on your site that modifies the `localStorage`.  Then listen to `window.onstorage` in your page to be notified when the caller id value changes.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you cannot access the files on the user's machine using javascript. This would be a huge security hole. You have to write a client (not web) application (windows app or whatever technology you are using).

Comment: @Matthew - Client applications can communicate with remote servers.  A client application on a user's computer can send whatever data from the user's computer it wants to the remote server.

Comment: @gilly3 I see what you mean:) But in this case, JS (or whatever) on my remote web app should access data (generated by another application) from the user's computer to select an item in a combobox (it's for a call-center: as soon as a client calls, the operator gets a file on his computer containing the caller ID, and the combobox on the website should be updated according to the caller's ID). I'll see if a Chrome plugin can help me with this, thanks for your help!:)

Answer (score 3):

this is not possible just using a browser, because as you said yourself it would`t be secure. You can use some kind of plugin which your users have to allow which then can access the local data on the computer.

Comment: Do you know such a plugin or were you suggesting me to code one?

Comment: I might be able to suggest something, if you tell me what data you want to access

Comment: Well, more precisely: "this is not possible using *just* native browser-page JavaScript" :-)

Comment: The remote website needs to get the data. If I share them a Chrome plugin, how will this plugin interact with the website? Actually the plugin should just select an item in a combobox based on the client's data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by access? does the server-side code need to grab additional info during processing a request?

Is this data that is exclusive to your app (that is, only you create, read, update it.)

If this data is exclusive to your app, then why not store it in [HTML 5 Local Storage](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/)